# Mongodb subfield select

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Hello I have the following db:

[image: a busy cat]

My question is how do I "SELECT name FROM posts Where thread=Sloan"

Because I'm trying into RockMongo shell : "**db.users.find({"posts.thread":'Sloan'})**" but it's return all the collection data

***** Using json-generator.com ********************

```
[
            '{{repeat(5, 7)}}',
            {
                id: '{{index}}',
                group: '{{surname}}',
                name: '{{firstName}} {{surname}}',

                posts: [
                    '{{repeat(25)}}',
                    {
                        thread:'{{surname}}',
                        sb:[
                            '{{repeat(100)}}',
                            {
                                id: '{{index}}',
                                name: '{{firstName}} {{surname}}'

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],

                users:[
                    '{{repeat(25)}}',
                    {
                        name:'{{firstName}}'
                    }]


            }
        ]
```

Comment: Can you post the sample structure of document containing posts and thread.

Comment: I don't follow what's wrong. Your "SQL" like request doesn't match with your hierarchical data structure. Could you post your desired outcome?

Comment: need to get sb array where thread = some name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify thing a little...
if you have a database looking like this:

[image]

Then if you do `db.users.find({ posts: { $elemMatch: { thread: "Sloan" } } })`,
you will obtain this (every element posts are included):

[image]

And if you do `db.users.find({"posts.thread":'Sloan'},{'posts.$':1})`,
you will obtain this (only the relevant post is included):

[image]

(By the way, it's faster to perform... and if you add an index on posts.thread, it will be even faster.)

One last thing, which I think can be misleading here. The `db.users.find({ posts: { $elemMatch: { thread: "Sloan" } } }, { name: 1 })` projection will give the element name 'gloria sharpe', but from what I understand from the question, he would prefer to obtain the name which is `post.thread.sb.name`. That's why he wants to have only the relevant post as an answer and not all the posts of that element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $elemMatch operator as follow to get what you need:

```
db.users.find({ posts: { $elemMatch: { thread: "Sloan" } } }, { name: 1 })
```

Comment: Returns same data as db.users.find()

Comment: Try it again, it's definitely correct. See https://gist.github.com/cheald/6291848

Comment: no it doesn't. 
In your case the stored object is the array, so the elemMatch return only the post with the array containing what you're looking for.
In his case, the stored object contains multiple arrays and he's trying to find the one containing his value. The elemMatch will return the whole object, containing the multiple arrays, because one of them contains the value he's looking for.

Comment: Selecting just the bits he's interested in is easily done with the second parameter to find(); it seemed from discussion that his problems was in getting the right records in the first place. Perhaps I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can retrieve directly the name, but you sure can retrieve the post you're looking for with a projection:

`db.users.find({"posts.thread":'Sloan'},{'posts.$':1})`

If you want more explanations about the `$` projection operator, look here: 
[MongoDB doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/)

Unfortunately I think you can't do `{'posts.$.name':1}` so you will have to extract the name in the resulting callback. (depends on which name field you want to retrieve... see my other answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $unwind:'$posts' }, 
    {$match: {'posts.thread': 'Sloan'} },
    {$group:{_id:'$name', posts:{$push:'$posts'} }});
```

Learning from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array) of the topic comments, I followed the answer of @Stennie, and give the answer, which i think is correct.

`$unwind`cut array to independend documents and `$group` make them to an array again.

Comment: @thefourtheye No, you can visit [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/) to see the syntax. `'posts.thread'`here can be writen as `posts.thread` (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation) aggregation operator as follow to get the flat JSON document to work on [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#match-aggregation) to check with each item's thread (i.e. posts.thread) :

```
var name_to_match = 'Sloan';
db.users.aggregate(
    {$unwind:'$posts'}, 
    {$match: {'posts.thread': name_to_match} },
    {$group:{_id:'$name', name: {$first:'$posts.thread'} }}
);
```

Now, the resulting output contains something like this:

```
{
   _id: '{{firstName}} {{surname}}',
   name: '{{surname}}'
}
```

Happy exploring MongoDB :)

Answer (score 0):

in the java you can fetch value from mongodb in like this:

```
MongoClient mongo=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("webportal");
DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("userdb");
String useremail=session("user");
BasicDBObject doc1=new BasicDBObject("email",useremail);
DBCursor cours=coll.find(doc1);
if(cours.hasNext())
{
    Map userjasondata=cours.next().toMap();
    String userid=userjasondata.get("_id").toString();
    session("userid",userid);
    String username=userjasondata.get("username").toString();
    String password=userjasondata.get("password").toString();
    String useremail1=userjasondata.get("email").toString();
    return ok(userprofile.render(username, username, password, useremail1)); 
}
```